# .htaccess for multiple APIs addresses

Tags: .htaccess, api

I have a domain that hosts 3 different Wordpress pages and two different APIs.

It works more or less like this:

- http://mywebsite.com (this one has a worpress in the root folder)
- http://mywebsite.com/wordpress2 (another wordpress installed in this subfolder and having another domain redirecting to it
- http://mywebsite.com/wordpress3 (same as above)
- http://mywebsite.com/backend/domain1/api/v1
- http://mywebsite.com/backend/domain2/api/v1

Now, I would like to have Rewrite rules for the API URLs so I can have:

- http://mywebsite.com/domain1/api/v1
- http://mywebsite.com/domain2/api/v1

While the URLs of the Worpress websites are left unaltered.

I have tried the below, but not working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule domain1/api/v1(.*)$ backend/domain1/index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule domain2/api/v1(.*)$ backend/domain2/index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone shed some light? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My bad, all. It was not working because the httpd.conf file had the line "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so" commented out.